# Infallible way to get reference to field in enum after writing to the enum

Tags: rust, enums

I'm writing a function that needs to do two things:

1. Write a value into an enum
2. Return a reference into the value that was just written

Here's what I've written:

```rust
enum State {
    Asleep,
    Awake { deeds: Vec<String> }
}

impl State {
    fn wake_up(&mut self) -> &mut Vec<String> {
        *self = Self::Awake { deeds: vec![] };
        match self {
            Self::Awake { deeds } => deeds,
            _ => unreachable!("WTF, how are we not awake!?")
        }
    }
}
```

The use of `unreachable!` seems inelegant though. Is there a way to write this function that avoids the need to handle an (obviously) impossible case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no way to do that. You can see [how it's implemented](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/ed937594d3912ced11f6f35a90bb8bf591909d2a/library/core/src/option.rs#L1207) in the standard library (Rust. 1.55) for `Option`:

```rust
    pub fn insert(&mut self, value: T) -> &mut T {
        *self = Some(value);

        match self {
            Some(v) => v,
            // SAFETY: the code above just filled the option
            None => unsafe { hint::unreachable_unchecked() },
        }
    }
```

Even if you use `unreachable!()` instead of the unsafe [`unreachable_unchecked()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.unreachable_unchecked.html) the compiler should be able to optimize it away as dead code.

Comment: Note: this should be optimized away even without unsafe on this very simple case https://godbolt.org/z/9njaorbGn